# Copying to USB 3.0 external hard drive is slow for the first seconds

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have a USB 3.0 WD My Passport external hard drive, and every single time I copy something to it, it starts very slow, like 30 MB/s (USB 2.0 speed), and then after a few seconds the speed increases to around 70 MB/s. Something like this:

[image: example]

This is not a huge problem or anything, I'm just curious on why this happens.

I have tested this on 2 different machines, both with Windows 10, and the behavior is the same.

Comment: Could it be that your CEIP (Customer Exerience Improvement Program) is checking data volume integrity and reporting the result to Microsoft? http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disallow-secret-customer-experience-improvement-program-collecting-information-in-windows-7/

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you try using a different USB cable with your WD My Passport external drive as well to see if the transfer rate speed would improve. I'd also advise you to keep at least one more duplicate of your data stored on the external HDD somewhere else as well. Having a backup means that you have at least two copies of your files on different locations. If changing the cable didn't help. I'd recommend running the QUICK & EXTENDED tests from [WD's Data LifeGuard Diagnostics](http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en). Give these a try and let me know how it goes! :) Good luck